# THREE.meshphongmaterial Not Working - Giving Black Color

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to use `THREE.meshphongmaterial` from this tutorial: http://solutiondesign.com/webgl-and-three-js-texture-mapping/

But it is not working and giving black color. Here is the jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/8hrk7mu6/12/

Problem is in line 32:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0x050505, color: 0x0033ff, specular: 0x555555, shininess: 30 } );
```

Why is it not working? If I use `THREE.MeshNormalMaterial`, then it works.

```
var material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
```

Later, I want to use texture from an image in my code. That is not working either. Only `THREE.MeshNormalMaterial` is working. Why?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Turns out it is necessary to add light. Without light, `meshphongmaterial` gives black color.

So I had to add something like this:

```
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff );
light.position.set( 0, 1, 1 ).normalize();
scene.add(light);
```

Got it from this link: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/2766

Comment: If you have O'Reilly WebGL from 2012, this fixes their example. Instead of `THREE.Light(0xffffff, 1.5)`, use `THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff )`

Answer (score 1):

Adding some ambient light to everything in the scene is the simplest solution:

```
scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040))
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add some Ambient Light or Point Light since,
MeshPhongMaterial reacts to Light & hence is only visible in presence of Light, for best results/visibility use below code:

```
const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.5);

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
pointLight.position.x = 2;
pointLight.position.y = 3;
pointLight.position.z = 4;

scene.add(ambientLight, pointLight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the emissive value was recommended by Terg's Three.js Learning QuickStart. The less lights you have the faster it renders.