# Model renders using MeshBasicMaterial but not MeshPhongMaterial

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I am making a page with three.js. I have made this code, which works:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
camera.position.z = 7;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xFFFFFF);
pointLight.position.x = 20;
pointLight.position.y = 20;
pointLight.position.z = 20;

scene.add(pointLight);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFFFFFF } );

var thebox, loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load("https://dl.dropbox.com/s/kasjdw78lx3bkk0/weirdshape.obj?dl=0", function (obj) {
  obj.material = material;
  obj.traverse(function(child) { child.material = material; });
  scene.add(obj);
  thebox = obj;
  render();
});

function render() {
  thebox.rotation.y += 0.01;
  thebox.rotation.x += 0.01;
  thebox.rotation.z += 0.01;
  requestAnimationFrame( render );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

This code does work, but when I try to change the `MeshBasicMaterial` to a `MeshPhongMaterial`, all I see is a black screen, even though my lighting seems to be in order. How can I fix this?

Comment: According to [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937966/three-meshphongmaterial-not-working-giving-black-color) it should work as long as there is a light - which you have. Are there any errors in the Javascript console (F12)?

Comment: No errors in the console. (http://codepen.io/htmlguy/pen/RWzMYN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read your source `.obj` file. Your model has no vertex normals. `MeshPhongMaterial` requires normals.

You can have three.js compute some. In your loader callback function, add:

```
if ( child.geometry ) child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

Note: Because the loader in this case returns `BufferGeometry`, this work-around is correct. If your loader returned `Geometry`, instead, then you may have to first call `geometry.computeFaceNormals()` if they do not exist either.

three.js r.73

Comment: I was just about to post this as an answer. Here's a working [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGQqgJ).